# Getting dates in reverse chronological order in .NET

Tags: c#

I am trying to print a set of dates from today.
Ex: If today is 06-Jan-14 and a CutOff value is 10,  the code should give me 10 days till 28-Dec-13.

Here is what I have tried:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                string month = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMMMMMM");
                int day = (int)DateTime.Now.AddDays(-i).Day;

                Console.WriteLine(day + " " + month);
            }
```

This gives the correct day but prints January every time.

Any clues are greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
  DateTime date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-i);
  Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:d MMMM}",date));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course it does... You're only calculating day of month, you're not recalculating the entire date.

If you say

```
DateTime olderDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-i);
```

then your olderDate will contain the correct date you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're only updating the day, not the date (and so missing the month).

What about something like this?

```
foreach (DateTime date in Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
    .Select(r => DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-r)))
{
    Console.WriteLine(date.Day + " " + date.Month);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your culprit:

`string month = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMMMMMM");`

That will always give you the month from the current date & time. Given that you're running the code in January, it is always outputting January. If you run the code next month, it'll always output February.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            var newDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-i);
            Console.WriteLine(newDate.Day + " " + newDate.Month);
        }
```